# Why do I get this Security Login Page although I configure the access Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**I want to acces to the H2 Database (localhost:9000/h2) without to this login page
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Any Idea why I am not able to configure the spring boot app in a way the the webconfigclass would be working.**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    }

}
```

This is the YAMPL FILE I am using:
YAML FILE:

```
  application:
    name: deliverynote
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:DELIVERYNOTE
    initialization-mode: always
    plattform: h2
    username: sa
    password:

  jpa:
    database-plattform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        generate_statistics: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

  banner:
    location: classpath:banner.txt

  javax:
    persistence:
      validation:
        mode: none
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: ALWAYS

springfox:
  documentation:
    swagger:
      v2:
        path: /v2/api-docs
server:
  port: 9000



jwt:
  secret: secret
  expirationMs: 4444444
```

This is the GRADL FILE I am using:

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "io.swagger.core.v3.swagger-gradle-plugin" version "2.1.7"
    id 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator' version '2.18.2'
}

group = 'com.deliverynote'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    implementation  'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testRuntime 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
    swaggerCodegen 'io.swagger:swagger-codegen-cli:2.4.2'             // Swagger Codegen V2
    swaggerCodegen 'io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-cli:3.0.5'  // or Swagger Codegen V3
    swaggerCodegen 'org.openapitools:openapi-generator-cli:3.3.4'     // or OpenAPI Generator
}

def webappDir = "$projectDir/src/main/java/angular-client/lieferschein-frontend/"
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["$webappDir/dist", "$projectDir/src/main/resources"]
        }
    }
}


swaggerSources {
    petstore {
        inputFile = file('petstore.yaml')
        code {
            language = 'spring'
        }
    }
}



test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: The image in your question is not visible. Pleas edit the question and add it.